# RxJava compose observable base on condition inside emmited items

Tags: rx-java2

I'm not sure I'm phrasing the question correctly, here's what I am doing: Downloading a image (if needed) applying some effects (blur) and setting it as the device wallpaper:

```
data class SetWallpaperIntent(val bitmap : Bitmap?, val url : String)

setWallpaperObservable.switchMap { setWallpaperIntent ->
    if (setWallpaperIntent.bitmap == null) {
        downloader.DownloadWallpaper(setWallpaperIntent.url)
            .flatMap {
                if (it is Result.Download.Success) {
                    Observable.just(setWallpaperIntent.copy(bitmap = it.bitmap))
                                            .compose(::blurWallpaper)
                                            .compose(::setWallpaper)
                                            .startWith(Observable.just(it))
                } else {
                    //Result.Download.Progress / Result.Download.Error events
                    Observable.just(it)
                }
            }
    } else {
        Observable.just(it)
            .compose(::blurWallpaper)
            .compose(::setWallpaper)
    }
}
```

This code works as intended but there are a few things I don't like from this approach:

1. I'm repeating code `.compose(::blurWallpaper).compose(::setWallpaper)`
2. I'm creating a lot of single item observables `Observable.just(it)`,

**So, my question is... is there a better way of achieving what I'm trying to do. Or is my approach the correct one?**

BTW, I've also considered using the `.publish()` operator, the code does not improve much

Comment: I think after creating an `Observable` that returns the image downloaded, you are basically done. I would do: `downloadWallpapaer(url).map(img -> blurWallpaper(img)).subscribe(img -> setWallpaper(img))`.

Comment: Yup, but sometimes I already have the bitmap, downloading it again would be a waste of resources

Comment: Ok, then your add an abstraction over that: `getWallpaper(url)` (in place of `downloadWallpaper`) that returns `downloadWallpapaer(url)` or `Observable.just(preexistingImage)`

Comment: I like that approach, let me try it and see how it fits my arch! thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I added more details in the answer. Give it a try ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can define a generic method that returns an image, regardless if it is already stored locally or if you need to download it. It will always be an `Observable<Image>`:

```
Observable<Image> getWallpaper(url) {
    if(imageExists(url)) {
        return Observable.just(getAlreadyDownloadImage(url));
    } else {
        return downloadWallpapaer();
    }
}
```

Where `downloadWallpapaer` has this signature:

```
Observable<Image> downloadWallpapaer(String url);
```

You also define two methods with these signatures:

```
Image blurWallpaper(Image image);

void setWallpaper(Image image);
```

Then you put all together:

```
getWallpaper(url).map(image -> blurWallpaper(image))
                    .subscribe(image -> setWallpaper(image));
```

In my opinion it makes sense to apply the wallpaper at the end of the chain, because you are consuming that data, you are not just transforming anymore. This is way I put it in the `subscribe` part.